Errorin compiling using color package and input
I'm using Overleaf to do a report for school, and in order to be readable, I've chosen to write every chapter in different .tex and then take them in the main .tex with all the packages, and do \input. The problem is that I'm using a table with \rowcolor using colors of \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} and when I try to compile it in the main .tex it gives me the error of "Undefined color" even though it is defined in the preamble. (If i try to compile the sub .tex alone without an \input, it would work perfectly though...).
I have no idea from where the problem comes.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Do you have \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} in the preamble of your main document?
